# Overlay multiple PNG images of various sizes within a container

Tags: html, css, image, web, png

I'm trying to make a character select container where pictures of characters show up within a rectangular container when their corresponding buttons are clicked. I currently have images showing up when the buttons are clicked, but I'm having trouble getting the images to scale properly and be appropriately cropped within the container.

The PNG images are of roughly the same size, but I may have to do some work modifying the images. Right now I'd just be happy for them to stay within the confines of a container.

HTML:

```
<section id="team-bar">
<img id="pos1" src="img1src.png">
<img id="pos2" src="img2src.png">
<img id="pos3" src="img3src.png">
<img id="pos4" src="img4src.png">
<img id="pos5" src="img5src.png">
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#team-bar
{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;

  img
   {
    width: auto;
    height: 300px;
   }
}

#pos1
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 0
}
#pos2
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  z-index: 1
}
#pos3
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 900px;
  z-index: 2
 }
#pos4
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 1300px;
  z-index: 3
}
#pos5
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 1700px;
  z-index: 4
}
```